# I can't get @Observable to work in Xcode 15 - 15.2

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have been trying to use `@Observable` since Xcode 15. I'm clearly doing something wrong but can't figure out what.

I have the following code in a Playground to show the issue:

[image: A Xcode screenshot that shows my issue]

Why is the @Observable not working? From Apple's sample code it looks like should just make the `Object` adopt `ObservableObject`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Code is text. Copy the text and paste it into the question, and format it as code. This allows us to copy the text from the question, paste it into Xcode, and try to run it.

Comment: Observable and ObservableObject are 2 very different things Observable is a replacement. Look at the migration guide online.

Comment: The error message explicitly says you can't assign your Object instance to a `@StateObject`. Did you try assigning an Object instance to something that is _not_ a `@StateObject`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Observable` is using existing data flow primitives like `State` and `Environment` instead of object-based equivalents such as `StateObject` and `EnvironmentObject`.

**Example:**

```
@Observable class Library {
    var books: [Book] = [Book(), Book(), Book()]
}
```

---

```
@State private var library = Library()
```